# Add-Type a type and it cannot read ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["..."]?

Tags: c#, powershell

There is a library which contains the following method.

```
public class Class1 
{
    public void X() 
    {
        //....
        var user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        Console.WriteLine(user); // Nothing printed.
```

And it's invoked by Powershell

```
$dllFolder = "C:\...\bin\Debug"

Add-Type -Path "$dllFolder\Class1.dll"
$test = new-object Class1
$test.X()
```

How to assign `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]` in the dll?

**Edit:**

I added `app.config` to the library project and the file `Class1.dll.config` contains the following lines.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="UserName" value="...." />
</appSettings>
```

However, it still doesn't print the value when running in powershell.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Does it have an app.config or web.config?

Answer (score 1):

In the app.config or web.config whichever your project has add the following...

```
<configuration>  

    ...

    <appSettings>
      <add key="UserName" value="whatever you want the value to be" />
    </appSettings>

    ....

</configuration>
```

Edit:

If you have access to the code, create the app.config in the root and rebuild. If you don't, then look for the config.ini in the build folder and update the UserName property. It should already be there.

Comment: I created an `app.config` in the folder `C:\...\bin\Debug\' but not working.

Comment: Do you have access to this application? Are you developing it, or is it a .dll that you are working with that you can't change the code in?

Comment: I have the source code now. I try to avoid to change it because it's not my code (other developers may change it). I may need to change it if I have to.

Comment: If you have access to the code, create the app.config in the root and rebuild. If you don't, then look for the config.ini in the build folder and update the UserName property. It should already be there.

Comment: I added the app.config and the file `Class1.dll.config` has been created with `<add key="UserName" value="...`. However, the code still didn't get its value.

Comment: I already created `app.config` and it still doesn't work. (The `Class1.dll.config` contains the config). There is no .ini file

Answer (score 0):

The following lines resolved the issue.

```
[appdomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "$dllFolder\Class1.dll.config")
```

Comment: That&#39;s a bit of a hacky way to do what I was trying to explain. But if it works...